# My Pip installation is broken and I don't know how to reinstall it [MAC/OSX]

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip

So I was frustrated at my python install because it wasn't installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper properly and tried to uninstall everything to try to get a fresh start, but now pip is broken and I'm getting these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==21.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2434, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2440, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-21.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
```

Is there any way to reinstall pip manually? The installation methods on the website don't work. Thanks!

Comment: Try searching `[python] install pip` on Stack Overflow. There are 97,000 results.

Answer (score -1):

### If you want Pip for Python 2

Seems like you have pip 21.0.1, [which does not support any Python 2 version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support). Probably, your pip is not broken, but unsupported for your Python. Maybe you will have to manually install a lower pip (use something like `python -m ensurepip`, or look for a `get-pip.py` script. See the reference [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/#supported-methods)).

### If you expect Pip to run under Python 3

Maybe your problem is: you want to run pip with Python 3, but it is running on Python 2. You can replace `pip` with `python3 -m pip`. That way, you call pip with Python 3.

Comment: The suggestion to use `apt-get` is not very useful, since the OP is running MacOS.

Comment: @TimRoberts you are right, thanks! I'll modify my post :)